# Need help fixing an R error with the free version

Tags: r

I'm in college and I use the free version of R/RStudio for my classes. My professors have never seen this error which is copied and pasted here:

> Warning: file ‘CAMP_3280_1.CSV’ has magic number 'TX,TG'   Use of save
> versions prior to 2 is deprecated Error in
> load("C:/Users/olape/Downloads/IPHY3280/Lab Assessment
> 1/data/CAMP_3280_1.CSV") :    bad restore file magic number (file may
> be corrupted) -- no data loaded

It's from an old lab and this particular data set has worked previously. This just recently started happening on both my laptop and desktop. We learned to import all our data sets with load() or manually from the environment clicking on the left most icon that is a tan manila folder with a green arrow which is what I do. I have to use R for my final and still have two labs to do so any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `load()` on a file that appears to be a .csv file? Have you tried `read.csv()`?

Comment: I'm using load because that is what I was taught in class. Using read.csv allows me to see it, but it isn't in the environment so I can't do the class assigned coding. I am using import dataset button in the environment and getting this error.

Comment: Use e.g. `my_df <- read.csv('CAMP_3280_1.CSV')` to assign it to `my_df` so it's in your environment. But the import dataset button will also assign it for you automatically, you can give it a name in the top left "Name" field.